# having trouble installing ubuntu 14.04.2 alongside Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 alongside Windows 7 (64 bit) but when I followed through the wizard it didn't give me the option to install alongside windows.

I then went back into windows and created a new partition. The install alongside windows option still didn't appear so I selected the 'something else' option and tried to select the new partition but it says that it's unusable. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to follow instructions but they don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

i think i may be able to help

goto windows delete the partition you created using partition magic or any software like that keep the space without partition goto ubuntu >something else>take that unformatted volume and make 3 volume >  1) /  ext4   2)  swap atleast same as ram 3)  /boot ext4  100MB  >install ubuntu grub will take care of the rest..if even then it dosent work hich is very unlikely if when you can boot into windows before you started installing ubuntu then maybe its GPT partition problem